# Ionic 4 PWA Splash screen change location path

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA sample app using Ionic 4 and it is working fine. My problem here is how can I change the splash screen?

Note: I can see the splash screen on the PWA app. But I don't know how to change it on below file?

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "short_name": "app",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: PWAs have no concept of a launch image in the manifest.json. The launch image is generated by the browser using an appropriate icon and the background color property. If you want to change the splash screen, you need to change the icons and images.


For reference: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Comment: @mhartington Is that mean we cannot have 1 image for home screen icon and another image for the spalsh screen?  i.e. cannot have 2 distinct images here on PWA.

Comment: @mhartington Thanks for the link. I got the idea. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PWAs have no concept of a launch image in the manifest.json. The launch image is generated by the browser using an appropriate icon and the background color property. If you want to change the splash screen, you need to change the icons and images.

For reference: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Comment: Yep, yep. For reference, check out `background_color`, `theme_color` and the icons configured in the manifest.json